# jQuery Modals: URL poiting to an specific modal (routing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `plainModal` (http://anseki.github.io/jquery-plainmodal/) plugin for displaying a set of modals in a page (http://codepen.io/Frondor/pen/xEBiA)

All the items are initializing the modals with no problems, but I need to share an URL like mywebsite.com/#some-modal so the page is loaded along with that modal active (#some-modal).

You can see my codepen above and try to enlighten me with some solutions.
I think I have to use some router script, but I don't have any idea about it. My site has to be purely static, html + js + css.

Although that "plainModal" plugin has some options about initialize method, I don't understand nor can't figure out the way to do it with URLs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the URL for a hash and then open a modal based on the hash:

```
// does url have a hashtag?
if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
      $('#sample-style').plainModal('open', {
duration: 500}, 'close', {close: $.fn.slideUp});
      console.log(hash);

  } else {
      // No hash found
  }
```

Right now this opens `$('#sample-style')` - which is the same div you are opening for every other click. When you add new content for each item you can use the code `$('#'+hash).plainModal('open'); // this opens <div id="{hash here}"></div>` to open a div based on the hash.

Comment: Thanks, this code seems to be what I need but it's not working. I've updated the codepen with it, but nothing happens. I'm trying with http://codepen.io/Frondor/full/xEBiA?#sample-button9
maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: See my update above. It didn't work for you because you have created the div#hash that it is looking for. I changed the code above to open the same modal the rest of your items are opening.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't work, look at the codepen now, its updated with your code and I'm pointing to the full page like this: http://codepen.io/Frondor/full/xEBiA?**#sample-style**
Note the **#sample-style** at the end of the URL, the page isn't loading the modal once it loads.
Maybe you couldn't understand my point, I need to be able to also trigger modals (one for each item) by typing the URL with the modal's hash ^^

Comment: For example, see the "news" on this page http://www.vorterix.com/fmrockandpop/rock/8589/grohl_le_tiro_flores
close that modal and see how every item opens a modal and the URL gets updated so you can use a link like the one I've just posted and once you access It, the modal show up, then you colse it and URL goes back to http://www.vorterix.com/fmrockandpop/